# Solidity abi does not include functions' return type

Tags: solidity

The following contract compiled with the latest compiler version does not give appropriate return types for functions.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address[] public players;

    constructor() {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function random() private view returns (uint256) {
        return
            uint256(
                keccak256(
                    abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, players)
                )
            );
    }

    function pickWinner() public restricted {
        uint256 index = random() % players.length;
        payable(players[index]).transfer(address(this).balance);
        // reset the contract
        players = new address[](0);
    }

    // function returnEntries() view restricted{

    // }

    function getPlayers() public view returns (address[] memory) {
        return players;
    }

    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }
}
```

Here is the ABI output from the terminal:

```
[
  {
    inputs: [],
    stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
    type: 'constructor',
    constant: undefined,
    payable: undefined,
    signature: 'constructor'
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: 'enter',
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: 'payable',
    type: 'function',
    constant: undefined,
    payable: true,
    signature: '0xe97dcb62'
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: 'getPlayers',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    stateMutability: 'view',
    type: 'function',
    constant: true,
    payable: undefined,
    signature: '0x8b5b9ccc'
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: 'manager',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    stateMutability: 'view',
    type: 'function',
    constant: true,
    payable: undefined,
    signature: '0x481c6a75'
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: 'pickWinner',
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
    type: 'function',
    constant: undefined,
    payable: undefined,
    signature: '0x5d495aea'
  },
  {
    inputs: [ [Object] ],
    name: 'players',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    stateMutability: 'view',
    type: 'function',
    constant: true,
    payable: undefined,
    signature: '0xf71d96cb'
  }
]
```

outputs: [ [Object] ], is undesired. An appropriate return type is expected. From the tutorial I'm following it looks like this (see the 'outputs' property):

```
[
  {
    constant: true,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'manager',
    outputs: [{ name: '', type: 'address' }],
    payable: false,
    stateMutability: 'view',
    type: 'function',
  },
  {
    constant: false,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'pickWinner',
    outputs: [],
    payable: false,
    stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
    type: 'function',
  },
  {
    constant: true,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'getPlayers',
    outputs: [{ name: '', type: 'address[]' }],
    payable: false,
    stateMutability: 'view',
    type: 'function',
  },
  {
    constant: false,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'enter',
    outputs: [],
    payable: true,
    stateMutability: 'payable',
    type: 'function',
  },
  {
    constant: true,
    inputs: [{ name: '', type: 'uint256' }],
    name: 'players',
    outputs: [{ name: '', type: 'address' }],
    payable: false,
    stateMutability: 'view',
    type: 'function',
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    payable: false,
    stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
    type: 'constructor',
  },
]
```

The tutorial uses an old version of Solidity. I want my project to use the latest version, I've fixed syntactic errors, and it compiles, however these return types are missing and this ABI does not work when calling functions on the contract. What am I missing here?

Edit: Full code: https://bitbucket.org/mantoska/public-lottery

Comment: Are you using javascript and console.log? If so you just need JSON.stringify the argument

Comment: @0xSanson It seems like I'm already doing that. I've added the code to Bitbucket, compilation code is in compile.js → https://bitbucket.org/mantoska/public-lottery

Answer (score 0):

0xSanson's suggestion helped. Printing out JSON object did not include nested objects. JSON.stringify on the result solved it.